# Frustrating problem with Stamps.com desktop app

Tags: mscorlib

I work in a warehouse and we have multiple PCs that work to ship out small packages. We have one PC that is dedicated to Stamps.com. Here is the situation I am hitting.
Stamps will work for some time without any issue, sometimes weeks sometimes days. Suddenly, when ever we try to open stamps there will be an error message and Stamps will crash out. I can not figure out what triggers this or how to fix it, so I use a workaround. I log out of Windows and sign back in under a new user name, then Stamps works again. Here is where it gets weird. If I take that user name that I just signed out of and sign into another PC that also has Stamps installed, it works just fine.
So, in short;
`PC1 + User1 = Crash`
`PC1 + User2 = Works`
`PC2 + User1 = Works`
`PC2 + User2 = Works`

The error messages I get reference mscorlib as the source of the issue, but since that is a core file of Windows, wouldn't that keep it from working despite the user name if that was actually the cause of the problem? I am going to paste the important bits of the crash report in case that helps.

```
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI5Ic.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxUTC.png)
```

I have done everything I know including reformatting the PC and starting fresh. It will start happening again within a couple of weeks.